# how to handle exception when a field in database does not allow nulls

Tags: c#, sql, exception

I have a field in the database that is nvarchar and it cannot be null.
I am having a problem to display the specific message when an error occurs.
When inserting in my database,I tried two things.
first:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxCity.Text))
    MessageBox.Show("This cannot be empty");
else  
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxCity.Text;
```

second:

```
try
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxCity.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty");

    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxCity.Text;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty");
        return;
    }
    else if (ex is SqlException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty");
    }
    throw;
}
```

the second one gives me the right message but it also gives me an exception where it says the scalar must be declared.how can I handle that?
I've tried to give it a db.null,but because a field does not allow nulls,the it gives me another exception,again that is not format,or sql.Can you tell me what kind of exception is this,or how can I handle this?

EDIT: At first I had a mistake,where it was supposed to be nvarchar sqldbtype,there was int.

Comment: You can simply put a check in c# code and can show any custom message. No need to go to database query.

Comment: How are you executing it, using which command I assume `ExecuteNonQuery` or is it `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: you mean before the sql part just to check if string is empty?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery..This is one one column from many that I insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is required but not supplied, you shouldn't try to insert it into the database anyway - of course that will cause an exception.

```
bool valid = true;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxCity.Text))
{
     valid = false;
     MessageBox.Show("This cannot be empty");
}

if(valid)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBoxCity.Text;
    //execute sql query here
}
```

As the other answer said, you should parse the text into an int as well.

Comment: this looks nice.but is there not a specific exception that throws must declare scalar?I thought that sqlexception would cover that

Comment: I checked you as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBoxCity.Text;
```

You defined your parameter to be of type `int` and you are giving it `string`. You need to parse the value from the TextBox to int.

```
int city = 0;
int.TryParse(textBoxCity.Text, out city)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.Int).Value = city;
```

Comment: sorry it was a mistake,but it stil does not work..
Can you tell me what exception throws the scalar must be defined?

Comment: @Alexander did you parse the value of the textbox and where did you receive this error

Comment: I thought that an SQLException would throw the scalar must be declared,but that is not the case.